# LINQ (to objects) , running several queries over the same IEnumerable?

Tags: c#, linq

Is it somehow possible to chain together several LINQ queries on the same IEnumerable ?

Some background,

I've some files, 20-50Gb in size, they will not fit in memory. Some code parses messages from such a file, and basically does :

```
 public IEnumerable<Record> ReadRecordsFromStream(Stream inStream) {
            Record msg;
            while ((msg = ReadRecord(inStream)) != null) {
                yield return msg;
            }
        }
```

This allow me to perform interesting queries on the records. 
e.g. find the average duration of a Record

```
 var records = ReadRecordsFromStream(stream);
 var avg = records.Average(x => x.Duration);
```

Or perhaps the number of records per hour/minute

```
var x = from t in records 
    group t by t.Time.Hour + ":" + t.Time.Minute into g
    select new { Period = g.Key, Frequency = g.Count() };
```

And there's a a dozen or so more queries I'd like to run to pull relevant info out of these records. Some of the simple queries can certainly be combined in a single query, but this seem to get unmanegable quite fast.

Now, each time I run these queries, I have to read the file from the beginning again, all records reparsed - parsing a 20Gb file 20 times takes time, and is a waste.

What can I do to be able to do just one pass over the file, but run several linq queries against it ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You might want to consider using [Reactive Extensions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/devlabs/ee794896) for this. It's been a while since I've used it, but you'd probably create a `Subject<Record>`, attach all your queries to it (as appropriate `IObservable<T>` variables) and then hook up the data source. That will push all the data through the various aggregations for you, only reading from disk once.

While the exact details elude me without downloading the latest build myself, I blogged on this a couple of times: [part 1](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2010/01/16/first-encounters-with-reactive-extensions.aspx); [part 2](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2010/01/19/linq-to-rx-second-impressions.aspx). (Various features that I complained about being missing in part 1 were added :)

Comment: Almost ceratinly the best way to do this, but there's a reasonably steep learning curve for the uninitiated.

Comment: @spender: It's definitely a big learning curve if you want to learn all of Rx and the uses. For *just these aspects* it's probably not too bad, *if* you can find a resource which is appropriately targeted.

Comment: @Jon: Just a question on a related note, why can't we run all the queries on this IEnumerable? they should be chained right, even without using Rx?

Comment: @Mahesh: No, because each aggregate is an "end point" as it were - when you call Sum, Average etc that uses immediate execution. Likewise if you want one "branch" of your query to group by one value and one branch to group by another, you have problems. LINQ works in terms of a single chain, basically.

Comment: Playing a bit around with Rx, I don't have this quite ironed out yet - but so far this seems quite feasible. Groans ...  If I just could connect an IEnumerable and have it pass through several pipelines in Powershell, while hooking it up to linq : `parseFileToEnumerable data/myGiantFile | aggergatorthatrunsalinqQuery1 | aggregator2  | aggregator3` I'd be a happy , happy man

Comment: @Anonym: You can use `ToObservable` to convert an IEnumerable to an IObservable. You just need to be careful how you do it :)

Answer (score 0):

I have done this before for logs with 3-10MB/file. Haven't reached that file size but I tried to execute this in a 1GB+ total log files without consuming that much of RAM. You may try what I [did](http://espiya.tumblr.com/post/1167578027/wonders-of-linq-querying-your-logfiles).

Answer (score -1):

There's a technology that allows you to do this kind of thing.  It's called a database :)

Comment: While a DB would do stuff more efficiently, I'd still have to run several queries against it, and the DB would pretty much have to do a full table scan every time for most of my queries. Anyway - this isn't about a db vs something else :)

Comment: +1 DB idea. Read everything into the DB once and query forever. Your comparison is kind of void as databases are optimized for such things, as is using linq to query such a thing. Also the size difference of the database compared to the files could be insanely large

Comment: @Jimmy You're right, the space difference is large, in the oposite way - loading these records into MyISAM tables on MySQL takes around 2.5 times more space (most dbs i've seen including SQL Server and Orcale uses even more space than the simple MyISAM tables),Archive tables yields less, but with limitations . It's possible db compression could help though, traditionally these records are stored gzipped, and zcat piped into the processing, leaving one core to do decompression - yielding significant speedup due to file size reduction.  Anyway, as said, the question is just about linq, not a db.